# What do I need to do to stop my Java app from triggering the Java 6 legacy download on OS X

Tags: java, macos, osx-elcapitan

I have a Java app available for download (AuctionSieve).

When you try to run it on OS X El Capitan (or Mavericks), it pops up "To open "AuctionSieve" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime." This is obviously a non-optimal experience for users. Besides which, I'd like it to use Java 8 so it can benefit from better security/performance/fixes etc.

What do I need to change about the way I package my app so it can just use the latest Java?

BTW My Info.plist file has JVMVersion set to 1.5+ and I've tried changing it to 1.8+ but that has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

It appears I should be using this:

https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler

Comment: Which is a fork of [Oracle's appbundler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html).

Comment: The lack of information on this from Oracle is appalling

Answer (score 1):

It appears from Java 8, this is the way Oracle means for it to be done:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html